# Removing a character from a sentence

Tags: java, algorithm

I am writing a java program that removes a character from a sentence. I am getting an error that says: The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type java.Lang.String. [line 35]

Any suggestions what this means.

```
public class Ex1Program {

public void start() {

String sentence = getSentenceFromUser();
int randomPosition = getRandomPosition(sentence);
printCharacterToBeRemoved(sentence, randomPosition);
String changedSentence = removeCharacter(sentence, randomPosition);
printNewSentence(changedSentence);

}

private String getSentenceFromUser() { 
System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
String sentence = Keyboard.readInput();
return sentence;
}
private int getRandomPosition(String sentence) {
int randomPosition = (int)(Math.random() * 14) +1;
return randomPosition;
}

private void printCharacterToBeRemoved(String sentence, int randomPosition) {
System.out.print("Removing " + sentence.charAt(randomPosition) + " from position " +                 randomPosition);

}

private String removeCharacter(String sentence, int randomPosition) {
String changedSentence = sentence.trim().CharAt(randomPosition);
return changedSentence;
}

private void printNewSentence(String changedSentence) {
System.out.print("New sentence is " + changedSentence);
}
}
```

Comment: why is it tagged with algorithm?

Comment: method names should always start with a lower case character and the package names should always be lower case.

Answer (score 3):

```
String changedSentence = sentence.trim().CharAt(randomPosition);
```

It's `charAt` not `CharAt`. Nevertheless, if you made this change, you would still be trying to assign a `char` to a variable that should be holding a `String`. You can use [`Character.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) to convert a character to a string.

---

P.S. If you want to delete characters in strings use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
String changedSentence = (new StringBuilder(sentence)).
                                         deleteCharAt(randomPosition).toString()
```

Comment: The error message that he has given us shows the correct method name though :)

Comment: ok. iam still getting an error that says: "Type mismatch; cannot convert from char to java.lang.string. Line 35. Whats it mean?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen The error is in this line: String changedSentence = sentence.trim().charAt(randomPosition);

Comment: `sentence.trim().charAt(randomPosition)` returns a `char`. So `String changedSentence` should be `char changedSentence`.

Comment: You can't simply assign a character to a String, you need to convert your character into String by using the Character wrapper class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString(char)